# Удаленная операционная система

Tags: сеть, ос

Здравствуйте!
Появилась задача построить сеть, в которой все компьютеры будут подключатся и работать только на удаленном сервере.
Т.е. включая компьютер, пользователю нужно ввести свой логин и пароль, он попадет на свой сетевой рабочий стол и может работать как и в обычной локальной ОС.
Подскажите, как можно такое организовать и возможно ли?

Comment: то что Вы хотите называется "терминальная система". Есть как платные так и бесплатные реализации серверов. Информации в интернете масса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Компьютеры пользователей в данном случае будут называться "тонкий клиент" (thin client по-английски). Есть решения для вашей проблемы на базе ОС Linux (можно реализовать и на Windows, но стоимость такого решения будет достаточно большой).
Попробуйте посмотреть, например, на вот эту сборку: [ThinStation](http://thinstation.pro/). Сам ей, откровенно говоря, не пользовался, но она упоминалась в [статье](http://habrahabr.ru/post/111620/) на Хабрахабре.
А вообще, поищите в Google информацию по запросам "тонкий клиент linux", "терминальный сервер linux" - думаю, Вы быстро найдёте ответ на свой вопрос.

UPD: Посмотрите, на Хабре вышла ещё одна [статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/270421/) на эту тему. Думаю, должна пригодиться.